# Why isn't my PHP class rendered?

Tags: php

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. I thought its semicolons but I added it everywhere. It throws an error when I visit this code in the browser saying unable to handle request. Can someone please tell me where did I make a mistake? I tried setting the property variables to just non-null values (simply declaring them) but that didn't work.

```
<?php
class Controller {
  /*add number of comments to quizComments tables'
   */
  $dbConnection = null;
  $userName = null;
  $userScore = 0;
  $currentQuestionIndex = 1;

  function connectToDb() {
    $mysql = 'mysql:dbname=cw;host=localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try {
      $this->dbConnection = new PDO($mysql, $username, $password);
      echo 'connected to database';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  };

  function getComments ($commentTable, $questionID) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM ('$commentTable') WHERE question_id = ('$questionID')");

  };

  function getQuestion ($questionTable, $questionID) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM ('$questionTable') WHERE id = ('$questionID')");
  };

  function addComment ($commentTable, $questionID, $author, $content, $emailContact, $dateAdded) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("INSERT INTO ('$commentTable') (question_id) VALUES ('$questionID')");
    echo 'Thank you for your comment. We will approve it soon.';
  };

  function addQuestion ($questionTable, $question, $answer1, $answer2, $answer3, $answer4, $correctAnswerIndex, $explanation, $author, $shortDesc, $dateAdded) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("INSERT INTO ('$questionTable') (question_id) VALUES ('$questionID')");
    echo 'Thank you for submitting. We will approve it soon.';
  };

  function progressToNextQuestion($questionTable) {
    $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $this->currentQuestionIndex);
  };

  function startQuiz ($questionTable) {
    if ($questionTable === 'QuizQuestionsBanking') {
      $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $this->currentQuestionIndex);
    };

    if ($questionTable === 'QuizQuestionsTrading') {
      $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $this->currentQuestionIndex);
    };
  };

  function checkAnswer ($questionTable, $questionID, $chosenIndex) {
    $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $questionID);
    $correctAnswerIndex = $question['solutionIndex'];
    if ($correctAnswerIndex === $chosenIndex) {
      $this->score++;
      $this->currentQuestionIndex++;
      $this->saveCurrentScore();
      $this->progressToNextQuestion($questionTable);
    } else {
      echo 'Wrong. Please try again.';
    };
  };

  function saveCurrentScore () {
    /* 1. make table called 'Leaderboard'
     * 2. insert into table 'username,score' values (username,score)
     */
  };

  function get15MostRecentQuestion () {
  /*sort descending, date */
  };

  function get15HighestRatedQuestion () {
    /* show different metric from usual: divide rating over # of votes*/
    /* sort descending, rating
     *
     * */
  };

  function get15MostCommentedQuestion () {
    /* sort number_of_comments descending
     */
  };

  function getTop10Contributors() {

  };

  function rateQuestion () {

  };

  function getLeaderboard() {
 /* SELECT * from Leaderboard
  */
  };

};

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get in the error log of your webserver?

Comment: You need to declare the properties correctly: *They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration* (see the manual).

Comment: There's not custom constructor, so as long as you haven't make a syntactical error it should be fine. What is missing from your question is the way you call this class and what exact error you get.

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid code, you don't need all the `;` and you have not defined the class property scopes. Enable `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)` whilst in development, this way you can see your fatal syntax errors.

```
<?php
class Controller {
  /*add number of comments to quizComments tables'
   */
  public $dbConnection = null;
  public $userName = null;
  public $userScore = 0;
  public $currentQuestionIndex = 1;

  function connectToDb() {
    $mysql = 'mysql:dbname=cw;host=localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try {
      $this->dbConnection = new PDO($mysql, $username, $password);
      echo 'connected to database';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  function getComments ($commentTable, $questionID) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM ('$commentTable') WHERE question_id = ('$questionID')");

  }

  function getQuestion ($questionTable, $questionID) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM ('$questionTable') WHERE id = ('$questionID')");
  }

  function addComment ($commentTable, $questionID, $author, $content, $emailContact, $dateAdded) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("INSERT INTO ('$commentTable') (question_id) VALUES ('$questionID')");
    echo 'Thank you for your comment. We will approve it soon.';
  }

  function addQuestion ($questionTable, $question, $answer1, $answer2, $answer3, $answer4, $correctAnswerIndex, $explanation, $author, $shortDesc, $dateAdded) {
    $this->dbConnection->query("INSERT INTO ('$questionTable') (question_id) VALUES ('$questionID')");
    echo 'Thank you for submitting. We will approve it soon.';
  }

  function progressToNextQuestion($questionTable) {
    $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $this->currentQuestionIndex);
  }

  function startQuiz ($questionTable) {
    if ($questionTable === 'QuizQuestionsBanking') {
      $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $this->currentQuestionIndex);
    }

    if ($questionTable === 'QuizQuestionsTrading') {
      $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $this->currentQuestionIndex);
    }
  }

  function checkAnswer ($questionTable, $questionID, $chosenIndex) {
    $question = $this->getQuestion($questionTable, $questionID);
    $correctAnswerIndex = $question['solutionIndex'];
    if ($correctAnswerIndex === $chosenIndex) {
      $this->score++;
      $this->currentQuestionIndex++;
      $this->saveCurrentScore();
      $this->progressToNextQuestion($questionTable);
    } else {
      echo 'Wrong. Please try again.';
    }
  }

  function saveCurrentScore () {
    /* 1. make table called 'Leaderboard'
     * 2. insert into table 'username,score' values (username,score)
     */
  }

  function get15MostRecentQuestion () {
  /*sort descending, date */
  }

  function get15HighestRatedQuestion () {
    /* show different metric from usual: divide rating over # of votes*/
    /* sort descending, rating
     *
     * */
  }

  function get15MostCommentedQuestion () {
    /* sort number_of_comments descending
     */
  }

  function getTop10Contributors() {

  }

  function rateQuestion () {

  }

  function getLeaderboard() {
 /* SELECT * from Leaderboard
  */
  }

}
```

**sidenote** Don't init your database in your controllers, else all your controllers will have this same code. Plus it's not invoked anywhere which may also be an issue ;p

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to declare access properties for functions?

Comment: you could do, but is not required for public methods, though its nicer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is you missed `access specifiers` for class variables

```
  $dbConnection = null;
  $userName = null;
  $userScore = 0;
  $currentQuestionIndex = 1;
```

to

```
  public $dbConnection = null;
  public $userName = null;
  public $userScore = 0;
  public $currentQuestionIndex = 1;
```

and in php `};`  is not a valid code replace it with }